# How can I repeat the command in for loop?

Tags: python, duplicates, maya

I'm trying to perform duplicate a sphere in z axis 10 times and then duplicate this whole copied spheres X and Y axis.

And I'm stuck after first step like this. Can I get some advice how I can repeat this duplication to X and Y?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.polySphere(r=0.5, sx=10, sy=10)
for i in range(0, 9):
    cmds.duplicate()
    cmds.move(0, 0, 2, r=True)
```

Comment: Do you simply need nested loops? Your question is not clear, but maybe you need to insert  `for j in range(0,9):` as a nested loop inside the `for i` loop. Just indent one level deeper at each nesting level you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make a cube of spheres, you just need 3 loops for each axis. To get the spacing right you multiply whatever the sphere's radius by 2:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

count = 4
radius = 0.5

for x in range(count):  # Loop in x axis.
    for y in range(count):  # Loop in y axis.
        for z in range(count):  # Loop in z axis.
            # Create a new sphere.
            transform, psphere = cmds.polySphere(r=radius, sx=10, sy=10)

            # Move it.
            cmds.move(
                x * radius * 2, 
                y * radius * 2,  
                z * radius * 2, 
                transform)
```

This will result like this:

[image: Cube of spheres]